# Xcode saying that the variable "beacon" is undeclared?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ibeacon

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
[super viewDidAppear:animated]
[[self.locationManager startRangingBeaconsInRegion: self.rangedRegion]
]}

- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
[super viewDidAppear:animated]
[[self.locationManager stopRangingBeaconsInRegion: self.rangedRegion]
]}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
self.tagname.text = [self.TagDetail objectForKey:@"Name"];
self.title = [self.TagDetail objectForKey:@"Name"];

NSString *proximity = @"near";


if ([beacon.proximity == CLProximityNear:]) {
    NSLog(@"Show near");
    [self.near setHidden:(NO)];
    [self.far setHidden:(YES)];
    [self.immediate setHidden:(YES)];




 }
else if ([beacon.proximity == CLProximityFar]) {  
    NSLog(@"Show");
    [self.near setHidden:(YES)];
    [self.far setHidden:(NO)];
    [self.immediate setHidden:(YES)];

}
else if ([beacon.proximity == CLProximityImmediate]) {
    NSLog(@"Show");
    [self.near setHidden: (YES)];
    [self.far setHidden: (YES)];
    [self.immediate setHidden: (NO)];

}
```

Heres the .h file

```
@interface TagDetailViewController : UIViewController
@property (nonatomic, strong) PFObject* TagDetail;
@property (strong, nonatomic)IBOutlet UILabel *tagname;
@property (nonatomic, strong)IBOutlet UIImageView *immediate;
@property (nonatomic, strong)IBOutlet UIImageView *near;
@property (nonatomic, strong)IBOutlet UIImageView *far;
@property (nonatomic, strong)IBOutlet UIButton *showOnMap;
@property CLLocationManager *locationManager;
@property CLBeaconRegion *rangedRegion;
@property NSUUID *artemisUUID;
@property CLBeaconMajorValue *major;
@property CLBeaconMinorValue *minor;
@property CLBeacon *proximity;

@end
```

Its telling me that the variable beacon is not identified, but doing so in the header file as *beacon doesn't remove any errors. What am I doing wrong? Im really new to this language so that is a large part of why Im running into errors, but I cant figure this one out.

Comment: You need to learn the fundamentals of C first.

Answer (score 4):

You don't have a variable named `beacon`, you have a `CLBeacon` object named `proximity`.